# iPhone - Status bar rotate even if the app supports only Portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, orientation, statusbar, landscape-portrait

I am developing an iPhone application that supports only Portrait orientation.
On my device everything works OK, but on my tester's the status bar is autorotating to landscape orientation. The rest of the view remains in Portrait mode.

My tester's device specs are these:
- iPhone 4
- Ver 4.2.8

I couldn't reproduce this error on my device (iPhone 4, 4.3.3).

Thanks!

Comment: have you configured plist file properly ? i.e. added only 2 orientation in support under the supported orientation key ? have you overridden -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation ?

Comment: @Jennis I didn't change anything. -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterface‌​Orientation is set by default to Partrait mode, and I have all the required entries in Info.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below function in your all viewController.m files.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown); // support only portrait
}
```

Add below key in your info.plist file

Initial interface orientation

And set it's value as "Portrait (bottom home button)"

Cheers.